# Jenkins DSL copy workspace to another job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I´m using Jenkins DSL, and I need to copy the workspace from one job to another, I´ve been looking for an API to do that without success.

Any idea how to do that using the DSL?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use the [clone SCM plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/clone-workspace-scm)

> This plugin makes it possible to archive the workspace from 
>      builds of one project and reuse them as the SCM source for 
>      another project.

[Which is supported by job-dsl](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#plugin/clone-workspace-scm)

```
publishCloneWorkspace(String workspaceGlob) {}
```

> Archives files for Clone Workspace SCM source.

```
cloneWorkspace(String parentProject, String criteria = 'Any')
```

> Add a SCM source which copies the workspace of another project. Valid
>   criteria are 'Any', 'Not Failed' and 'Successful'.